# Retrieve created_at timestamp from pgsql

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7

I'm a Python newbie. I wrote an sql query to retrieve created_at timestamp in pgsql. When I called the method `strftime('%x')` on it, I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT created_at FROM rating WHERE user_id = 'xxxxx' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2;
```

When I printed the result of the query, I merely got `[(3L,)]` which is just one of the two created_at times expected. How do I convert this back to python's datetime?

Comment: what is SQL type of created_at ?

Comment: Use `\d rating` in an interactive `psql` session

Comment: created_at is in timestamp

Comment: What gives the same query in interactive psql?

Answer (score 0):

strftime looks like it's not callable, have you imported DateTime?

Also, when calling strftime you'll need to format it, for example created_at.strftime('%y %B %d').

Finally, it's actually quicker to process and convert the time in SQL rather than using strftime.

A simpler and more performant solution would be to just format in the SQL itself:

```
SELECT to_char(created_at,'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM rating WHERE user_id = 'xxxxx' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: I'd try that. datetime was imported.